# React - Detail page is not showing json data but console.log shows up

Tags: reactjs, react-router, state, react-props

I am creating a details page to load json data for a specific id from earthquake list. The home.js file contains the state and the routes and the list of earthquakes which are links to the detail page. The detail.js page should show the details of each earthquake for the link clicked.
I am getting the state and data in the console but it is not displaying on frontend.

I want the link in the home page to display the detail page for that particular earthquake id.

The state is passed through posts from { Home } component to the { Detail } component and I am reading JSON through require.

Please help. I would really appreciate it!

Home.js

```
const Home = (props) => {
 const posts = require('/src/components/features.json');
 console.log(posts)

       return (
           <>
               <Container fluid={true}>
                   <Row>
                       <CardDeck className=" no-gutters ">
             {randomData.map((random) => {
               return (
                 <div key={random.metadata.api}>
                   <h2>{random.metadata.title}</h2>
                 </div>
               )
             })}
                           {posts.map((postData) => {
                               console.log(postData.id);
                               return (
                 <HashRouter>
                                   <div key={postData.id} className="container">
                   
                                           <ul className="a">
                       <li>
                       <Link to={{
                                 pathname: `/detail/${postData.id}`,
                                 state: {posts : postData}
                                 }}
                               >
                                 {postData.properties.title}</Link>
                       </li>
                                           </ul>
                   
                   <Route
                   path="/detail/:id"
                   name="earth"
                   component={Detail}
                   exact 
                   />
                   
                                           <li className="b">
                                               {postData.properties.mag}
                                           </li>
                                           <li className="c">
                                               {postData.properties.time}
                                           </li>
                                       </div>
                   </HashRouter>
                               );
                           })}
                       </CardDeck>
                   </Row>
               </Container>
           </>
       );
 }



export default Home
```

Detail.js

```
const Detail = ()=> {
    const { state } = useLocation();
    console.log(state)
    return (
      <div>
            <div>
              <strong>Id:</strong> {state.posts.id}{" "}
            </div>
            <div>
              <strong>Name:</strong> {state.posts.properties.mag}{" "}
            </div>
        <Link to="/">
          <button>Back</button>
        </Link>
      </div>
    );
  };
  

  export default Detail;
```

Comment: So just to make sure I'm understanding this correctly: you are currently getting the data as expecte in the console.log, but it isn't being displayed when you render it in the `Detail` component? If this is the case, instead of doing just a console.log, do `console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state)))` and let me know what is displayed.

Comment: Yes, I tried that and I get the same output on the console. There is no change.